# How to render my videos from s3 with the return of link using Storage in react for AWS s3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I have a react app that will pull down a list of keys from s3 and then loop through them and get the links needed. I need to use the links generated in the render part of my app to show videos.

```
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import { Storage} from 'aws-amplify'
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
import { withAuthenticator} from "aws-amplify-react";
import config from "./aws-exports";
Amplify.configure(config);
const result = ""
class App extends React.Component {

onChange(e) {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  const filename = e.target.files[0].name;
  console.log("filename", filename)
  Storage.put(filename, file, {
     contentType: 'video/mp4'
   })
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
 }

render() {
Storage.list('', {
    level: 'public'
  })
  .then((result) => {
    Storage.get(result[1].key, {
        level: 'public'
      })
      .then((result) => {

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  })


return (
  console.log("result", result), <
  ReactPlayer url = {
    result
  }
  playing / >

  )
 }
}

export default withAuthenticator(App, true);
```

I want the results from Storage.get to be able to be rendered for the video playback

Comment: Please tell people what errors you are getting

Comment: @YikSanChan I'm not getting any errors, that is the issue :( it just doesn't know the result from s3 down in the render part

Comment: You can add log. For example, when you get `result`, log it by `console.log`, this should give you more info

Comment: Also, you should not make async call in `render`. Do it in `componentDidMount`. Read https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount plz

Comment: @YikSanChan Thanks man, this comment put me in the correct direction and now it works :D